# Allowing a div to always fill the width left in a div

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design

working on a few design changes for my website on tablets and trying to work on this idea.

So the basic structure is like so:

```
<div id='container'>

    <div id='leftbox'>Content</div>
    <div id='rightsidebar'>Sidebar</div>

</div>
```

What i want, is for the container to be 100% width, but keep a right hand sidebar at 260px but allow the leftbox div to always fill the width left.

I have made a fiddle to show. But heres the CSS from that fiddle first:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #999;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#leftbox {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #666;
  float: left;
}

#rightsidebar {
  width: 260px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #333;
  float: right;
}
```

Heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X2w3D/

In that example I have just set the width of the left div to 50% to give it a width. The aim is that if the user was to be on a web browser, and resize then there would be no gap between the leftdiv and the rightsidebar. So the rightsidebar is always the same width, but the leftdiv will always fill the rest of the div up in width.

Thanks, Craig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) model? It was designed to answer this kind of problem.

I updated your fiddle and added an example solution: http://jsfiddle.net/X2w3D/4/

I used `display:flex;` on the container, then added `flex-grow:1;` to the `#leftbox`

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #999;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex; // ADDED THIS

}

#leftbox {
    flex-grow:1; // ADDED THIS
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #666;
    float: left;
}
```

**Edit:** If you need retro-compatibility for the `flexbox` model, I cannot recommend the amazing [flexbox.less](https://github.com/ProLoser/Flexbox.less) enough. It has saved my life quite a few times.

Comment: In that fiddle the sidebar on the right changes width and you decrease the container size :/

Comment: Absolutely true, I went too fast sorry. I updated my answer with a better solution.

Comment: @user2921557 you might want to accept my answer now that it works. Btw I love the fact that you currently have 404 reputation :)

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested on `calc`

`width: calc(100% - 260px);`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X2w3D/2/)

[Referrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: Hero. I was looking and wondering if there was something EXACTLY like this. My search a while back yielded no results so I just guessed it wasn't that easy. Many thanks!